# Python Mechanize 307 Error

Tags: python, mechanize

I am trying to fill out forms on 2 different pages, with the second page's form's action being a .cgi link. I can fill out both forms absolutely fine, but when I try to submit the second form, mechanize returns a 307 error, which is generated from the server.

I looked into the error, and it says it is a temporary redirect error, but I thought mechanize could handle redirects?

The code in question (I include the urls I am attempting to access so the code is runnable):

```
from mechanize import *

counter = 0

br = Browser()
br.set_handle_redirect(HTTPRedirectHandler)
br.open('http://www.nationstates.net/page=create_nation1')
br.select_form('form')
br.form['name'] = 'faleraider' + str(counter)
br.form['currency'] = 'duobloon'
br.form['animal'] = 'parrot'
br.form['slogan'] = 'Arr, raise your new sails!'
br.form['email'] = 'falserraider' + str(counter) + '@sharklasers.com'
br.form['password'] = 'raider'
br.form['confirm_password'] = 'raider'
br.submit(name='create_nation')

br.select_form('form')
br.form['Q0'] = ['SD',]
br.form['Q1'] = ['SD',]
br.form['Q2'] = ['SD',]
br.form['Q3'] = ['SD',]
br.form['Q4'] = ['SD',]
br.form['Q5'] = ['SD',]
br.form['Q6'] = ['SD',]
br.form['Q7'] = ['SD',]
br.form.find_control('legal').selected=True
#br.set_debug_http(True)
response2 = br.submit() #error originates from here
print response2.get_data()
```

The forms fill out fine, it is the error code the server is returning (I don't know why the server returns that as an error, or why mechanize is not handling it). Note that I did add the redirect handler, it did not help.

The page the form posts to is /cgi-bin/build_nation.cgi

I have tried to use urllib + urllib2, Beautiful Soup, and splinter, but they all returned similar, or worse results.

Answer (score 0):

After first submit, don't you think that you have to capture what is returned?
I have not used mechanize though!

Comment: That's what `response2 = br.submit()` does. At one point, I changed the mechanize source to stop the error from being raised, and when I printed out reponse2.get_data() (which gets the response from the server), it showed a 307 error page.